# UnicodeEncodeError when run SSD test code

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, object-detection

I'm trying ro run the [tensorflow/ssd_tests](https://github.com/balancap/SSD-Tensorflow) code with spyder in win10 (python 3.5 tensorflow 1.1).

And I got an error like:

```
    File "D:\software\anaconda\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\jsonapi.py", line 43, in dumps
    s = s.encode('utf8') 
    UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcd5' in position 2896: surrogates not allowed`
```

I run the code step by step, and I found when run the code `provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider()` the error occus.
In the file *dataset_data_provider* which function DatasetDataProvider()`in, code`key, data = parallel_reader.parallel_read()`from`from tensorflow.contrib.slim.python.slim.data import parallel_reader` will course the error.

The function of *parallel_read()* is this:

```
    def parallel_read(data_sources,
              reader_class,
              num_epochs=None,
              num_readers=4,
              reader_kwargs=None,
              shuffle=True,
              dtypes=None,
              capacity=256,
              min_after_dequeue=128,
              seed=None,
              scope=None):
    data_files = get_data_files(data_sources)
    with ops.name_scope(scope, 'parallel_read'):
      filename_queue = tf_input.string_input_producer(
    data_files, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=shuffle, seed=seed,
    name='filenames')
      dtypes = dtypes or [tf_dtypes.string, tf_dtypes.string]
      if shuffle:
        common_queue = data_flow_ops.RandomShuffleQueue(
      capacity=capacity,
      min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue,
      dtypes=dtypes,
      seed=seed,
      name='common_queue')
      else:
        common_queue = data_flow_ops.FIFOQueue(
      capacity=capacity, dtypes=dtypes, name='common_queue')
      summary.scalar('fraction_of_%d_full' % capacity,
               math_ops.to_float(common_queue.size()) * (1. / capacity))
      return ParallelReader(
    reader_class,
    common_queue,
    num_readers=num_readers,
    reader_kwargs=reader_kwargs).read(filename_queue)
```

Is *dtype* the cause of this error?
And how shoud I get rid of this?
Thank you!

**I have found the reason. When the model was loaded correctly, the error disappeared.**